# Date Validation and date database insertion in Laravel 5

Tags: date, post, laravel-5

I have a `promo_starts_at` and `promo_ends_at` fields in DB with type `date`
The date is entered via bootstrap date-picker in the following format `01/20/2019`

```
  "promo_starts_at" => "01/22/2019"
  "promo_ends_at" => "01/30/2019"
```

I have the following set of rules in my ProductManager:

```
if($parameters['type'] == 'integer'){ $data[$field] = intval($request->input($field)); }
if($parameters['type'] == 'string'){ $data[$field] = $request->input($field); }
if($parameters['type'] == 'decimal'){ $data[$field] = $request->input($field); }
if($parameters['type'] == 'text'){ $data[$field] = $request->input($field); }
if($parameters['type'] == 'bool'){ $data[$field] = $request->input($field) ? 1 : 0; }
if($parameters['type'] == 'date'){ $data[$field] =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->input($field))); }
```

Additionally, I also have a set of validation rules:

```
    'promo_starts_at' => [
        'type' => 'date',
        'validation' => 'date'
    ],
    'promo_ends_at' => [
        'type' => 'date',
        'validation' => 'date'
    ]
```

I cannot post the date into the database for some reason.

I have also tried different validation rules, such as `date_format:Y-m-d|after:today`, but nothing changes.

I have found a fix for this problem, the last rule should be changed to the following:

```
$data[$field] =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->input($field)));
```

This has fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a fix for this problem, the last rule should be changed to the following:

```
$data[$field] =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->input($field)));
```

This has fixed the problem for me.